# Stop direct access to all files in a folder, but allow ajax requests

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, security

Not sure if this is possible, but...

Lets say i have process/login.php

if a user visits that page directly i have a check to see if the user has come from posting a form etc. If not, they get 404'd.

However i am now building up plenty of process scripts etc and they all require different checks as some are just included etc.

Is there a way to 404 a user if they directly access any files? using htaccess?

I know there is

```
Options -Indexes
```

But that only stops the showing of the files. You can still visit any of the files directly.

If there isnt a stable way of doing it then i will manually go around all the files and secure them but would rather the user just cant see anything.

Comment: A php based solution that worked for me can be found here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/23449295/2883501

Answer (score 3):

Ok its not 100% bulletproof since HTTP REFERRER can be spoofed.

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yourdomain\.com/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^process/login\.php$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: +1 This is the only thing you can (indeed) do. It's still a publicly accessible file.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using sessions. You can check for the appropriate session and redirect if the session is not valid.

Also, I would attempt to throw a 404 error, I would simply redirect them to you home page. A 404 is a specific error thrown by your server (Apache, Nginx, etc.) when a it receives a GET request that it cannot process. You shouldn't "spoof" these errors by sending a 404 from your backend code. Doing so will fill your sever error logs with "noise."

Answer (score 2):

Check `if (empty($_POST))` and redirect to your home page if the condition is met. This will make sure that your form processing code has been POSTed to.